# Parse part of XML response to another request in Postman

Tags: javascript, xml, postman

I have to test a few webservices(SOAP) in Postman who response is in XML format and I want to use a part of response from the first request to the second request body. 
It wouldn't be such a big problem if the first request  response would have the same number of rows(IDK how to call them), but the number of **** may be different for each response.
 
**First Request Response**

```
<ListResponse>
            <Response>
                <success>1</success>
                <callId>?</callId>
            </Response>
            <portfolio>
                <total>?</total>
                <Balance>?</Balance>
                <!-- The number of "List" may be different for each response -->
                <List>
                    <Text1>?</Text1>
                    <Text2>?</Text2>
                </List>
                <List>
                    <Text1>?</Text1>
                    <Text2>?</Text2>
                </List>
                <List>
                    <Text1>?</Text1>
                    <Text2>?</Text2>
                </List>
                <List>
                    <Text1>?</Text1>
                    <Text2>?</Text2>
                </List>
                <List>
                    <Text1>?</Text1>
                    <Text2>?</Text2>
                </List>
                <ticket>?</ticket>
            </portfolio>
    </ListResponse>
```

**Second Request Body**

```
<Campaign>
     <Request>
        <Portfolio>
           <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
           <List>
              <Text1>?</Text2>
              <Text2>?</Text2>
           </List>
        </Portfolio>
     </Request>
  </Campaign>
```

I tried to parse using responseJson['ListResponse']['portfolio']['list'] then to save it in a Env. Variable and then to use that in the second Request Body, but I'm unable to transform JSON to XML. 
Another thing that I tried is to split the response, but again I couldn't use this solution beacuse the number of List may be different for each reasponse. 
I ran out of ideas, if you guys have any ideas I would appreciate your help

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution, might not be the best one, but it's working <3.
In the Tests tab from Postman I made this script.

```
 var ListJSON=responseJson['ListResponse']['portfolio']['list']
 var ListLength=responseJson['ListResponse']['portfolio']['list'].length
 var List='';
 for(var i=0;i<ListLength;i++){
    var eachList='';
    var Text1=ListJSON[i]['Text1'];
    var Text2=ListJSON[i]['Text2'];
    eachList=`<List>
         <Text1>`+Text1+`</Text1>                 
         <Text2>`+Text2+`</Text2>
              </List>`;
    var List=List.concat(eachList);
}

pm.environment.set('List',List);
```

Then I would use the Variable that I stored in the second request and It would look like this:

```
<Campaign>
     <Request>
        <Portfolio>
           <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
          {{List}}
        </Portfolio>
     </Request>
  </Campaign>
```